# Multiline comment in awk

Tags: awk

I would like to know how to use multi line comment in awk. As of now I have been using # to comment a single line. Could someone guide me regarding this. Thank you.

Comment: there is no multiline comment in awk

Comment: Then any suggestions of how to make the code elegant

Comment: @NandaKumar "making code elegant" is somewhat broad. My suggestion would be to take a look at some larger AWK programs in books/references and use those to guide you.  I have this one http://www.amazon.com/The-AWK-Programming-Language-Alfred/dp/020107981X, and might get this http://www.amazon.com/sed-awk-Edition-Dale-Dougherty/dp/1565922255. This one looks promising too: http://www.amazon.com/Effective-awk-Programming-3rd-Edition/dp/0596000707. I've learned a lot from studying other's code (not just with AWK). And in fact I do it every day here on SO :)

Answer (score 20):

There is no multiline comment in AWK, but you can fake it if you need to. Here is one technique that works at least in GNU AWK (`gawk`):

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
0 {
    You can use
     0 to cause
     a block to
     not execute
     or be parsed
}

{
    print $2, $1, $3
    if (0) {
        You can use if (0)
        in a similar manner
        inside a block
    }
    sum += $4
}

0 && /pattern/ {    # prepend "0 &&" to other conditions to turn off a block
    print
}
```

It's nice to be able to have multiline comments for commenting out sections of code during debugging. I wouldn't necessarily use this technique for documentation since it may not be guaranteed that the non-code text would not be parsed for syntax errors.

It seems to also work in `mawk`.

Comment: This is nice to know but it does not work if the "comment" contains things like `don't`. In other words, the "comment" is not parsed for grammar but it must be a lexically correct awk token stream.

Comment: @lhf: True, it has its limitations. That's one of the reasons I warned against using it for documentation (although I didn't state it).